# Defining range using regular expressions in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this code:

```
(1..40).map(&:to_s).grep(/[2-3][0-9]/)
```

So when I type in `[2-3][0-9]` it will print all the numbers in the range (which is between 20 and 39). How can I do it without defining the range (i.e. in this case it is "1..40") so it works for any regular expression that I type into the brackets?

So similar code to

```
(1..40).map(&:to_s).grep(/[2-3][0-9]/)
```

that would work without `(1..40).map` part.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this an hour ago?

Comment: Do you actually need to use a regex, or is that just how you are used to doing it in Bash? It would be better to deal with an actual range of numbers if you have that functionality available, as you do in Ruby.

Comment: I'm just trying to write a short webapplication that would allow me to type in any regular expression I want 
and return the numbers in that range.

So, let's say I type in a long one 10[5-6][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9] which wouldn't work for mapping range 1-40. So I am looking for a universal code that wouldn't require to map the range.

Comment: So, if you were to type in "10[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" you want an array with 10 million numbers in it?

Comment: Please don't ask questions multiple times. It won't improve the answers you get, and it dilutes the quality of your question. Plus, you'll gather downvotes as people realize that's what you're doing.

Comment: As commented in your previous question, this isn't a good use of regex. A pattern is great for locating or extracting a number, but determining whether that number is within a certain range suddenly balloons the pattern into a horrendous mess, so don't go there. Patterns should be made as simple as possible, otherwise you open up logic holes that are hard to test for; Instead, use the pattern to find your number, then use normal logic to determine whether it's in the desired range.

Comment: Hi Itay and Max. I've tested your code for [2-3][0-9] and it didn't return anything. Am I doing anything wrong? Thank you for your help by the way :-)

Comment: Can you put comments about my answer on my answer?  it's less confusing :) I've edited it with a fix.

Comment: It's working. I needed this tool to make my day easier at work. I have to set up power and temperature threshold for servers in regular expressions.

Comment: I bet that if you took a step back, and asked a question saying something like "i'm given some threshold values as a regular expression, and i need to test whether the values from a system are within that threshold.  What's a nice way of doing this?" you would get a much better way than what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is awful, and you really probably don't actually want to do this, you just think you do.  But, FWIW:

```
def this_is_awful(string)
  results = []
  string.split("|").each do |section|
    #example section is "5[0-3][2-4]"
    section_digits = []
    section.split(/[\[\]]+/).select{|s| s.size > 0}.each do |range_string|
      range_digits = range_string.split("-").select{|s| s.size > 0}
      arrays = (range_digits[0]..range_digits[-1]).to_a
      section_digits << arrays if arrays.size > 0
    end
    #now we need every combination of these
    section_digits[0].product(*section_digits[1..-1]).each do |combination|
      results << combination unless results.include?(combination)
    end
  end
  #at this point, results will be like [[5, 0, 2], [5, 0, 3], [5, 0, 4], etc].  Sort these and convert them to digits via strings
  results.sort.collect{|arr| arr.join}
end
```

eg

```
irb(main):075:0> this_is_awful("5[2-3]")
=> [52, 53]
irb(main):076:0> this_is_awful("5[2-3][3-9]")
=> [523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539]
irb(main):077:0> this_is_awful("5[2-3][3-9]|10[1-7][3-8]")
=> [523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078]
```

Btw i would say that this question has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails.

EDIT:  I just edited this to work more generally, with any enumerable (so it will work with letters too for example).  You now get strings back but you can convert them to integers if you want with `.collect(&:to_i)`

eg

```
irb(main):122:0>     this_is_awful("a[b-e][f-g]")
=> ["abf", "abg", "acf", "acg", "adf", "adg", "aef", "aeg"]
```

EDIT 2: fixed a bug for when it starts with an array

Comment: Thank you so much Max, you've made my day :-)

Comment: Actually, I tried 10[3-6][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9] and it didn't give me the correct result. I'm so sorry.

Comment: What were you expecting, and what did you get?

Comment: I was expecting range 1030-1069 and 1100-2099, the same what appears when I run command "(1..3000).map(&:to_s).grep(/10[3-6][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]/)" in the Ruby console.

Comment: I've just tested it - they are exactly the same, apart from the numbers being in a different order.  In your example above, they are in numerical order, in my method, they come out in order of how they appear in the source string.  So, in a simple example, for "[3-4]|[1-2]", your code above would generate ["1", "2", "3", "4"] and mine would generate ["3", "4", "1", "2"].  If you want them to be the same, you can call `.collect(&:to_i).sort` on the results from my method, to convert them into integers instead of strings, then sort them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is brute forcing. It's inefficient and slow. It's just a wrong approach so forget about RegEx.

You are going to need a real algorithm. So I made one for you...

I'll assume that the your input will only include numbers: `1` and ranges defined like that: `[2-6]` or any combination of the two, resulting in a string like: `1[2-3][5-7]9`.

Imagine this is a vector (array) of possible digits with two types of elements:

- range of possible digits.
- fixed digit (which is a range of the number to the same number)

Our example for the input `1[2-3][5-7]9` converted should look like:

```
[ [1,1], [2,3], [5,7], [9,9] ]
```

The first element in this array (`[1,1]`) is the range for the first digit, the second (`[2,3]`) for the second digit, and so on.

It's relatively easy to turn it into something like this. This is an array of arrays with two elements - start and end number of each range.

So what you need to do now is output each possible value. This can be done with a simple recursion for every digit, starting a new branch for every of it's possible values.

Here is an example implementing that recursion:

```
def recursion(array, number = '')
    return if array.empty? # Don't bother if the digits array is empty

    # iterate over each possible value of the current pair
    (array[0][0]..array[0][1]).each do |i|
        if array.length <= 1 # If the digits array is empty (contains only the current range)
            # then an entire number would have been generated, so print it
            puts number + i.to_s
        else
            # Start a new branch passing the array (without the current element)
            # and the generated number until this moment
            recursion(array[1..-1], number + i.to_s)
        end
    end
end

array = [ [1,1], [2,3], [5,7], [9,9] ]

recursion(array)
```

Following this approach you can make the function as complicated as you can.

I provided you with the routine on how to compute the numbers themselves, but not on how to create the `array` which I hope you can handle.

This is harder to implement and certainly doesn't contain all the features of RegEx but is fast and will generate numbers as hell.

*P.S. Wow.. This took me an hour to create and debug. Hope it helps.*